# C# ImageMagick dll loading error

Tags: c#-4.0, imagemagick

I'm using the Magick.NET-x64.dll file in my project that converts pdf files to jpg images. But when I moved from a 32-bit windows processor to a 64-bit machine the following error encountered:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x64, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=2004825badfa91ec' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load
a program with an incorrect format.
```

I am getting this error when I build the project. How can I avoid this?

Comment: You need separate DLLs for the 32bit and 64bit versions, or you need to set your code to always compile as 32bit code and then use the 32bit version and add a 32bit DLL.

Comment: I have tried to do that as well, but then I get a different error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET-x86.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Did you install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 on the new server?

Comment: I did but actually some of the binaries were missing earlier. But now I worked it out.